# Eclipse Mars 2 UI Bug - How can I configure Tomcat to have x seconds of timeout on startup?

Tags: eclipse, tomcat

First of all I wonder why Tomcat does not get like an infinite timeout for the startup when in debug. I came here because I was debugging my server in his startup phase and got the error:

> Tomcat was unable to start within 45 seconds.

Well, the simple solution would be to increase the time using the server view. I just recently updated to Mars 2 and unfortunately this is what it looks like:

[image]

So does anybody know if there is a file where I can configure this since using the UI does not work? And additionally: Is it possible to tell Tomcat to simply wait forever when in debug mode?

---

Btw in case it helps: This is under Ubuntu 14.04

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try to edit attribute **start-timeout** of *server* element in `$WORKSPACE/.metadata/.plugins.org.eclipse.wst.server.core/servers.xml`.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8" standalone="no"?>
<servers>
<server start-timeout="145" stop-timeout="15" server-type-id="org.eclipse.jst.server.tomcat.70" ...>
    <list key="modules" value0="test::org.eclipse.jst.jee.server:wstest::jst.web::3.0"/>
</server>
</servers>
```

BTW, I open *Tomcat server* configuration page in *Servers view*. The max value of that spinner component is **9999**.

Comment: My file was located at `$WORKSPACE/.metadata/.plugins/org.eclipse.wst.server.core/servers.xml` but it worked! **Note:** I also had to restart Eclipse after changing the .xml file.